# Program ordinals and omega squared

Tags: code-golf, metagolf

A program ordinal is a (possibly transfinite) ordinal which can be assigned to programs in some language depending on their output.

To be more specific:

- Strings that give no output have ordinal 0
- Programs that output a program of ordinal n have ordinal n+1
- Programs P0 outputting multiple programs P1, P2... Pn have ordinal S, where S is the supremum of the set of program ordinals corresponding to the programs P1, P2... Pn

Your goal is to create the shortest possible program with program ordinal ω*ω, also writable as ω<sup>2</sup> or omega squared.

Output is required for a program. As well as this, the output must go through STDOUT or closest equivalent.

All programs printed by your program must be delimited by any string, so long as the delimiter is always the same. (`acbcd` and `accbccd` are allowed, but not `acbed`) These delimiters must be the only output other than the programs themselves, unless your language must output trailing characters.

Here is a program-ordinal ω program created in pseudocode, which generates programs of the form "exit, print(exit), print("print(exit)")...:

```
x=exit
loop{
print(x)
x='print(#x)'
}
```

Within each iteration of the loop, x is printed and then wrapped in print() (exit becomes print(exit)). # is put before x in pseudocode to indicate that it is the variable x and not the actual alphabetical character x.

The shortest program (measured in bytes) which has program ordinal ω<sup>2</sup> wins. Have fun.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48931/make-the-largest-infinity-that-you-can).

Comment: I think you need to include a definition for the first uncountable ordinal or this isn't really clear.

Comment: How exactly is outputting multiple programs defined?

Comment: So, if P0 outputs P1, where P1 has ordinal n, P0 has ordinal n + 1, but if P0 outputs P1 and P2, where both P1 and P2 have ordinal n, P0 has ordinal n? Since n is the supremum of the set {n}.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but in your example program of ordinal \$\omega\$, shouldn't `0` be replaced by a program that prints nothing (for example, `exit` or `print ""`)?  What your example prints first is the number `0`, which isn't a program (at least in most languages).

Comment: I take it that the pseudocode line `x="print(x)"` is meant to have `x` be replaced with its value within the string?

Comment: I really like the idea of the question, but it could have used some time in the Sandbox to hammer out some of the details.

Comment: @Abigail Yes. P0 obtains ordinal n since n is the supremum of the set of program ordinals given to the programs it prints.

Comment: @xnor I think that you are wrong, since the line is meant to replace x with the string "print(x)", where x is the value itself.

Comment: @Andrew That's what I meant to express. The confusing bit in the pseudocode is that `x='print(x)'` makes it looks like `x` is being replaced with the literal eight-character string `print(x)`, since that's how it would be processed in most languages. Usually some special symbol is used to mean that the value of the variable `x` is to be inserted into the string, rather than just the letter `x`.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but why is this question closed?  I thought it was clear and a good, interesting challenge -- and it has some answers already.  What clarification are people looking for?  (OP added the recommended delimiter modification.)

Comment: I think the issue is within the "self contained output" clause.

Comment: @Andrew  Then just take that out.  After all, it's not necessary to assign ordinals to quines; there are lots of programs that you aren't assigning ordinals to.  And you don't need those to construct a program whose ordinal is \$\omega^2.\$  (Also, you might want to take out the remark about uncountable ordinals.  It's certainly true that every ordinal assigned to a program is countable, but that doesn't affect the challenge at all, and it may discourage solvers who aren't that familiar with ordinals and think that they're missing something important.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector My issue is as commented by UnrelatedString, There is no explanation of how you distinguish between separate programs in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
Nest[Nest[HoldForm@*Print,#,∞]&,,2]
```

Thinking process:

```
y=w="x=0;Do[Print[x=\"Print[\"<>ToString[x,InputForm]<>\"]\"],∞]";Do[Print[y=StringReplace[w,"0"->ToString[y,InputForm]]],∞]
```

This first solution is the same as the other solutions, it is a port of Surculose Sputum's answer, so I *think* it is correct. ToString[x,InputForm] sanitizes a string to be fed into it's own print statement. w stores the program that outputs the 0,1,2,3,... or the first ω, and y stores the program fed into itself n times that outputs ω+1,ω+2,ω+3..., when looped gives ω*ω.

But that got me thinking, all that nested loop does, is, well, Nest. Which is a function in Mathematica, and Mathematica also can output "held" code, meaning no handling strings. Which means I could change w to

```
w="Nest[HoldForm@*Print,0,∞]"
```

Which makes w hold a program that doesn't have a loop for n=0,1,2,3... , but has ω more directly inside it by just holding prints. Alternatively NestList would return the same n as the original program, but why waste time with printing 1, and then 2, and then 3, when we can just print a program ω.

But if I do that for the first part, what's stopping me from doing that to the last part?

```
Nest[HoldForm@*Print, Nest[HoldForm@*Print, 0, ∞], ∞]
```

Well, now we have that ω<sup>2</sup> program we wanted, but it looks a bit... referential? Like it's code is nesting itself. Nesting nests time!

```
Nest[Nest[HoldForm@*Print,#,∞]&,0,2]
```

That looks very nice. And since the program of just the keyword "Null" (not to be mistaken for the null program) is a valid program, we can golf out that 0.

And it could even be changed for arbitrary ω<sup>n</sup>'s, or even ω<sup>ω</sup> for just two bytes more. If anyone wanted to run this themselves, I would change out the ∞ for a 3.

Side note: if you really wanted to keep using strings instead of holdform:

```
Nest[Nest["Print["<>ToString[#,InputForm]<>"]"&,#,∞]&,,2]
```

is 57 bytes, and good for learning.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>67 63</s> 65 bytes

```python
x=""
while 1:x="x=%r\nwhile 1:x='print%%r;'%%x;exec x;"%x;print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8JWSYmrPCMzJ1XB0ArIqbBVLYrJQwioFxRl5pWoqhZZq6uqVlinVqQmK1RYKwGZYAmFiv//AQ)

Use the same strategy as [@UnrelatedString's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205277/92237), be sure to check out and upvote his answer!
Repeatedly print out programs with ordinal \$0, \omega, \omega2, \omega3,\ldots \$. The programs are separated by the string `";\n"` (a semi-colon and a new line).

**[68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8JWSYmrPCMzJ1XB0ArIqbBVLYrJQwioFxRl5pWoAgVj8tRVVSusUytSkxUqYvKUgGywnELF//8A) to separate programs by a blank line.**

#### Explanation

A program with ordinal \$n+1\$ is created by adding a print statement around an \$n\$-ordinal program:

```python
print <escaped string of ordinal-n program>
```

A program with ordinal \$\omega(n+1)\$ is created by repeatedly printing out programs with ordinal \$\omega n, \omega n+1,\omega n+2,\ldots\$

```python
x = <string of omega*n program>
while 1:
  x = 'print %r' % x
  exec x
```

Note the use of `%r`, which escapes the given string `x`. This way, we don't have to worry about quote and new line characters.

Finally, a program with ordinal \$\omega^2\$ is created by repeatedly printing out programs with ordinal \$0, \omega, \omega 2,\omega 3,\ldots\$:

```python
# string of program to go from omega*n to omega*(n+1)
s = "x=%r\nwhile 1:x='print%%r'%%x;exec x" 
# current omega*n program, start with n=0
x = ""
while 1:
  # create the omega*(n+1) program from omega*n
  x = s % x
  # print it out
  print x
```

Comment: Not too sure I'd call it *the* same strategy when I reinvent the while loop and think I'm clever for using `exec` for it

Comment: Your new code looks quite close to the string literal in the loop inserted inside itself.

Comment: @xnor I tried to extract the similar part into a common string. However, making sure that everything is escaped probably was super hard, and the overhead ended up being too large.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum I haven't read through your code, but when you say, "Finally, a program with ordinal \$\omega^2\$ is created by repeatedly printing out programs with ordinal \$\omega n, \omega n+1,\omega n+2,\ldots\$:", should the sequence of ordinals at the end be "\$0, \omega, \omega 2, \ldots, \omega n, \omega(n+1), \omega(n+2), \ldots\$"?

Comment: @MitchellSpector Thanks for catching that. I copy-pasted from the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes

```python
s='def l(f,x):\n print(x+"\\n")\n l(f,"%s%r)"%(f,x))'
exec(s)
l(s+"\nl('print(',",'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYu9CoAgEIB3n0IO5O7IrS3oTdxKKZBL1MGe3qzW7yfd9bhk7r2suPugIwXbeHGiUz6lUpvAOQEe4FVgiskM5qsYlW9@o8IqUhmhRMJ/QwsWkXt/AA)

I... *think* this might be valid? This should print a sequence of programs, separated by blank lines, with ordinals ω, ω·2, ω·3, ω·4, ..., but the reasoning by which I arrived at those ordinals was pretty shaky and I've already forgotten what it even was, so I'd appreciate being shown that I'm completely wrong. The general idea of it is that one program with ordinal ω+ω = ω2 is one which prints a program with ordinal ω, then prints a program that prints that program (so that it has ordinal ω + 1), then prints a program that prints that, and so on... and the part I don't feel too solid about is doing that with the program with ordinal ω·2 to get to ω·3, and iterating to get ω<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: A minor point: (This isn't a comment on your code, which I haven't checked.)  Ordinal multiplication isn't commutative.  You meant \$\omega 2\$ and \$\omega 3\$, not \$2\omega\$ and \$3\omega\$.  When you apply the definition of ordinal multiplication, \$\omega 2 = \omega+\omega\$, and \$\omega 3 = \omega+\omega+\omega\$, but \$2\omega = 3\omega = \omega.\$

Comment: I think that the resulting "list of programs" must be clearly defined (it must be possible to determine where one program ends and the other begins).

Comment: That's my concern as well, but until the challenge author responds I've gone and erred on the side of convenience. I will add a less ambiguous version now though.

Comment: I added the rule that delimiters must exist, so I think the second version should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 47 bytes

```
-[[<]>[>.]+0]<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]
```

The `0` represents a null byte `\x00` and will be used as the delimiter between programs. I will also use `1` and `ÿ` to represent the bytes `\x01` and `\xff` respectively.

The idea here is to use the program `<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ` with some leading and trailing `1`s to represent ordinals between 0 and \$\omega^2\$. The number of trailing `1`s represent how many multiples of \$\omega\$ there are, and the number of leading `1`s is how much is added to it. The program `11111<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ111`, for example, represents \$\omega3+5\$ and prints the \$\omega3+4\$ program `1111<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ111`.

```
11111<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ111     // w3+5
11111                                           // Do nothing
     <[<]>-                                     // Decrement the first character of the code (a '1')
           [?????????????????????]              // If it's not zero do this (not in this case)
                                  >[.>]         // Print the remaining code
                                       ÿ111     // Do nothing
```

The leading `1`s will continue to be deleted until the \$\omega3\$ program is reached.

```
<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ111  // w3
<[<]>-                                  // Decrement the first character (the '<')
      [                     ]           // If it's not zero
       +                                // Increment it back to '<'
        [>]<-                           // Decrement the last character of the code (a '1')
             [?]                        // If it's not zero do this (not in this case)
                <[         ]            // Loop
                  [<]+                  // Add a '1' to the start of the program
                      [>.]<             // Print the code with a trailing '0'
```

This will print the following programs (delimited by `0`s):

```
<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ11       // w2
1<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ11      // w2+1
11<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ11     // w2+2
111<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ11    // w2+3
...
```

These programs will keep deleting the leading `1`s until the program starts with `<`, then they delete a trailing `1` and print programs with an increasing number of leading `1`s. This continues until the 0 program is reached.

```
<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ     // 0
<[<]>-                                  // Decrement the first character (the '<')
      [                     ]           // If it's not zero
       +                                // Increment it back to '<'
        [>]<-                           // Decrement the last character (the 'ÿ')
             [<]                        // Go to the start of the code
                <[?????????] >[??]ÿ     // Halt without printing anything
```

The \$\omega^2\$ program simply prints the \$0, \omega, \omega2, \omega3, ...\$ programs.

```
-[[<]>[>.]+0]<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]     // w^2
-                                                   // Append a 'ÿ' to the end of the code
 [          ]                                       // Loop
  [<]                                               // Find the '0'
     >[>.]                                          // Print the program with a trailing '0'
          +                                         // Add a '1' to the end
```

This prints:

```
<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ     // 0
<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ1    // w
<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ11   // w2
<[<]>-[+[>]<-[<]<[[<]+[>.]<]]>[.>]ÿ111  // w3
...
```